# How to group by each 5 rows and put the values into list columns

Tags: python

I need to group by every 5 rows and put the value in to list

| Data set | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1.2 | 4 | 5 |
| 1.3 | 6 | 7 |
| 1.4 | 8 | 9 |
| 1.5 | 10 | 11 |
| 2.1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2.2 | 4 | 5 |
| 2.3 | 6 | 7 |
| 2.4 | 8 | 9 |
| 2.5 | 10 | 11 |

into

| Data set | Value | a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1 | Value 1 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 10 |
| 1.1 | Value 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 9 | 11 |
| 2.1 | Value 1 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 10 |
| 2.1 | Value 2 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 9 | 11 |

Comment: What format is the original data set in?  Are you reading it from a file?  Is it already in a list, dict, dataframe, or some other structure?  Is it guaranteed that for each Value there will only be 5 sub-values x.1-x.5 correlating to a through e?  What have you tried in your code so far?

Comment: it reads from CSV file with a timestamp in the first column each minute has 170 samples. each sample records 3 values x,y and z 

df1 = data.groupby('Time.')['Value0'].apply(list).reset_index(name='X')
df2 = data.groupby('Time.')['Value1'].apply(list).reset_index(name='Y')
df3 = data.groupby('Time.')['Value3'].apply(list).reset_index(name='Z')